# Set the display of my table with radio button using radio buttons mvc

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, radio-button

well I searched on every web site but I didn't find what I want so : 
I will be easier for you, to see what I have :
[my page ;)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9zBS.png)

So for each radio buttons, I want to set the display of my table.

Ex : if I pick "Alphabétique", the values sorted in alphabetical order.

I knew I needed to use Ajax, but I'm absolutely not comfortable with that. In addition to that, I am programming my project in MVC.
I made some research on Google, Stack, OpenClassroom, etc..
And I don't understand exactly what I need to do in Ajax or where I need to add the instructions.
So here is my code :

controllerBoutique.php (Controller):

```
<?php 
 require('../Views/codes/boutique.php'); 
 require('../Models/vehicule.php');
 $query = getVehiculesByAlpha();
 require('../Views/codes/tabAffich.php');
?>
```

boutique.php : (View)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Rentcar - Boutique</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Views/styles/style2.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
  <?php require("menu.php");?>
  <section id="section" class="main-section cleanbg">
    <div class="container">
      <label>Trier par :</label>
      <div class="single-col">
        <div class="styled-input-container">
          <div class="styled-input-single">
            <input type="radio" name="fieldset-1" id="radioAlpha" value="Alpha" checked="checked"/>
            <label for="radioAlpha">Alphabétique</label>
          </div>
          <div class="styled-input-single">
            <input type="radio" name="fieldset-1" id="radioModel" value ="Model"/>
            <label for="radioModel">Modèle</label>
          </div>
          <div class="styled-input-single">
            <input type="radio" name="fieldset-1" id="radioKm" value ="Km"/>
            <label for="radioKm">Kilométrage</label>
          </div>
          <div class="styled-input-single">
            <input type="radio" name="fieldset-1" id="radioDispo" value ="Dispo"/>
            <label for ="radioDispo"> Disponible </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="search">
      <label class="lblSearch"> Rechercher :</label>
      <input type="text" id="search-box" class="search-box">
      <button class="btnSearch">Chercher</button>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="section" class="main-section cleanbg">
    <div class="container">
      <hr>
```

tabAffich.php : (view table)

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="table">
   <div class="row header">
     <div class = "cell">Marque</div>
     <div class = "cell">Modèle</div>
     <div class= "cell">Kilométrage</div>
   </div>
   <?php 
     while($res = $query->fetch()){
   ?> 
   <div class="row">
     <div class ="cell">
     <?php echo $res['nom'];?>
   </div>
   <div class="cell">
     <?php echo $res['modele'];?>
   </div>
   <div class="cell">
     <?php echo $res['km'];?>
   </div>
   </div>
   <?php 
     }
     $query->closeCursor();
   ?> 
  </div>
</div>

</div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

vehicule.php (Model):

```
<?php 
 function getVehiculesByAlpha(){
  try{
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ProjectRentcar;charset=utf8','root','root');
  }catch(Exception $e){
    die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
  }
  $query = $db->query('
    SELECT nom, modele, km 
    FROM Vehicule V, Marque Ma 
    WHERE V.numMarque = Ma.numMarque
    ORDER BY nom, modele');
  return $query;
  }

function getVehiculesByModel(){
  //Same code with order differently
}
function getVehiculesByKm(){
  //Same here
}
```

So I would know how can I change the display of table when I click on a specific radio button, and some help in Ajax  
Thanks you in advance ❤️

Answer (score 0):

you can achive this using only PHP but sure it would be better for UX to achive this with Ajax (for you too, you will learn more).

1) So first you need a javascript function that will trigger when you click on `input[type=radio]` and for example if you click on radio button with `id == radioAlpha` it will run a function using Ajax request to your `vehicule.php?sort=alphabetique`. If you click on radio button with `id == radioModel` it should run a function using Ajax request to your `vehicule.php?sort=model` - you can send data using POST or GET request with Ajax, how do you like.

2) You should then change your `vehicule.php` file, it should also contain something like this:

```
if ($_GET['sort'] == 'alphabetique') {
    // run function with sort for alphabetique
    // echo data with json format for example or even with html
}
if ($_GET['sort'] == 'models') {
    // run function with sort for model
    // echo data with json format for example or even with html
}
...
...
```

3) Yor file `tabAffich.php`

```
<?php 
while($res = $query->fetch()){
?>
 <div id="sorttable"> // Add this line
 <div class="row">
     <div class ="cell">
          <?php echo $res['nom'];?>
     </div>
     <div class="cell">
         <?php echo $res['modele'];?>
     </div>
     <div class="cell">
         <?php echo $res['km'];?>
     </div>
 </div>
 <?php 
  }
 $query->closeCursor();
  ?> 
 </div>
```

Back to Ajax request, when it would be a successfull call with response you can generate new data in `<div id="sorttable">` container. You need some knowledge of javascript how to clear data and generate a new from ajax response but its not very hard to learn.

I hope that will help you a little bit in understanding how you can use ajax in this situation.

There are really many ways to get the effect you want to achieve, and the one I've presented is quite simple, I think.

Comment: Thanks it's true, it's very simple, I didn't think about this solution, thanks a lot ;)